# programmatic fit in matlab, order of unknowns in fittype options

Tags: matlab

i'm trying to programmatic fit a function in matlab, and i need to set the upper and lower boundaries of my unknowns. but i don't know in which order i should put them. for an example:

```
    func = ['heaviside(time).*-2*v.*exp(-a.*time).*sin(sqrt(w^2-a^2).*time+phase)'];
    curve = fittype(func,'independent','time','dependent','volt');
    opts = fitoptions( 'Method', 'NonlinearLeastSquares' );
    opts.Lower = [3000 0 -0.1 100000];
    opts.StartPoint = [4000 1.7 0.05 140000];
    opts.Upper = [5000 3.14 0.1 150000];
```

but how matlab will know how to match these boundaries to the unknowns?

in the example I've put the boundaries corresponding to the order [a, phase, v, w], but of course matlab didn't read them in that order....

Comment: it appears from the documentation that the variables are referenced in order of appearance from left to right, so I think that you would have your limits be something like [v, a, w, phase]. However, you have small system, with vastly different ranges on the bounds, so I would advise trying different orders and find a fit that makes physical sense. You could also make a test expression of the form a*x + b*x^2 + c * a + d * x^3 and see which order the limits go here.

Comment: actaully i can open cftool and than genertate code to see in which order matlab puts them. but i am sure that there must be a way to do it entirely programmatic. and it is not the order of the appearance in the function....by the way, in the code above the opts suppose to be in the fittype function 
fittype(....,'options',opts)